# How would I output HTML in the specified format from a Ruby array?

Tags: html, ruby

I have an array of various food items, like so:

```
1% milk (low fat)
100% fruit juice blend (juicy juice)
100% whole wheat bagel
100% whole wheat bread
100% whole wheat cracker (triscuit)
2% milk (reduced fat)
alfredo sauce
all-bran cereal
all-fruit preserves (no added sugar)
...
wrap sandwich (vegetables only)
wrap sandwich (vegetables, rice)
yellow cake with icing
yellow corn (corn on the cob)
zucchini bread
zucchini or summer squash
```

Now, I know how to get an HTML list of all the elements in the array in Ruby. I could do something like this:

```
puts "<ul>"
foods.each do |e|
  puts "<li>#{e}</li>"
end
puts "</ul>"
```

However, I don't know how to break the list into different sections for each letter, so that I can take this array and output a bunch of seperate lists of items (in HTML), like this:

```
<div class="grid_1">
  <h1>#.</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>1% milk (low fat)</li>
    <li>100% fruit juice blend (juicy juice)</li>
    <li>100% whole wheat bagel</li>
    <li>100% whole wheat bread</li>
    <li>100% whole wheat cracker (triscuit)</li>
    <li>2% milk (reduced fat)</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="grid_1">
  <h1>A.</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>alfredo sauce</li>
    <li>all-bran cereal</li>
    <li>all-fruit preserves (no added sugar)</li>
    ...
```

How would I create this output in Ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Enumerable#group_by](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001497) to group your values by the first character, like this:

```
    grouped_food = food.group_by { |f| f[0] }
```

This would not put all the food starting with a number in a separate group, though. This would take some more magic:

```
    grouped_food = food.group_by { |f| 
        f[0] =~ /[0-9]/ ?  # if the first character is a number
        "#." :             # group them in the '#.' group
        f[0].upcase+"."    # else group them in the 'uppercase_first_letter.' group
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first perform a [`group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001497) on your input list

```
foods = foods.group_by{|x|x[0]=~/[a-z]/i?x[0].upcase():'#.'}
```

and then proceed as before.

```
foods.each do |key, list|
  puts "<div class='grid_1'>"
  puts "<h1>#{key}</h1>"
  puts "<ul>"
  list.each do |e|
    puts "<li>#{e}</li>"
  end
  puts "</ul>"
  puts "</div>"
end
```